# Where should I put "never"?

Tags: word-order

A) I never should have done it.

B) I should never have done it.

C) I should have never done it.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Have a look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+should+have%2C+should+never+have%2C+should+have+never&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20should%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20never%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20never%3B%2Cc0). A better question would be, why is one preferred over the other? Why is there a difference in usage rate?

Comment: Google: adverbs of frequency. That is the research you need to do before posting a question like this. (never, ever, sometimes, always, sometimes. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

All 3 are correct English sentences that mean the same thing, just personal preference.

Comment: I agree, with the caveat that Example C sounds more archaic and less idiomatic, and Example A is likely the most common/idiomatic in current usage.